# Can`t find the xpath and how to add value to the iframe

Tags: python, xpath, iframe, text

I have a problem for getting the iframe and to write something on it .
attached is a photo of the iframe .

So far I`ve tried  :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(__tcfapiLocator)--> this is the id of the frame

driver.quit()


description = '/html/body/iframe'
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(description).send_keys("Hello")
```

also I found a path like this '//*[@id="description_ifr"]'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2obRV.jpg)

it has also this id where the text is stored
<textarea id="description" class="" placeholder="

so if I write something manul the value is there "asasaas"

asasaas

Comment: Your code looking wrong. Can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: You're trying to call `driver` after you did `driver.quit()`. That won't work

Comment: @Prophet can I write you somehow in private .

Comment: It is about a description box

Comment: @Jason can I contact you ?